# Convert Column with Different Date formats into only One format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Column with 3-4 different date format. How can I convert this into only one format?

Some Examples from column [DateAdded]

```
2004-04-19  13:36:52
28.02.2005  09:29:34
01.09.2013
```

I'm trying to get this into format: `2004-04-19  13:36:52`
 
and without losing the Dates.

Comment: You should have used a `DateTime` column right from the beginning. Never ever store dates in `varchar` columns!

Comment: @Texx, are `28.02.2005` and `01.09.2013` both in `dd.mm.yyyy` format? Because if there are values in `mm.dd.yyyy` format then you could be out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of a date is just a representation. You must use DateTime for store dates, if you have stored your dates in a varchar you can:

1. Alter table and add a column for the dates formatted correctly
2. Make an update with the following where conditions:

   ```
   date_col like ('____-__-__ __:__:__')
   date_col like ('__.__.____ __:__:__')
   date_col like ('__.__.____')
   ```

   The character '_' means any character (but just one) in like function.
3. Use the function CONVERT for transform your VARCHAR to DATETIME, see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp
4. Store your datetime values in the new column.